# gcloud compute scp - Connection Failed (Sometimes with 4010 Error Code)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, gcloud, scp

"**Connection Failed**

You cannot connect to the VM instance because of an unexpected error. Wait a few moments and then try again."

When I tried to copy file from one virtual machine to another using scp, ssh client loses connection. Command that I run is the following:

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse file_name account@instance_name:~/folder --zone zone_name --project project_name
```

What can be the reason of it?

[image: Error screenshot:]

Comment: Hello, have you found an answer for this? I'm facing something similar when I try to deploy a Google Cloud VM instance via Terraform. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have opened port 22, which is the port that allows communication with SSH. If you are not sure, you can create a rule by going to VPC -> Firewall Rules -> port 22.

Here is an article that can help with [allowing SSH connection](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)

This other article can help you [troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)

You can also run the following command to check which ports you have open `netstat -tuplen`, make sure you have port 22 listening.

Comment: Port 22 is open and properly defined in Firewall Rules.

Comment: Can you please share the complete 4010 Error Code you get? The only 4010 error code I was able to find is the following “Code: 4010 - Connection via Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy Failed”.